# How to properly add Bootstrap and JQuery Javascripts?

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, twitter-bootstrap, scripts

I am developing my WordPress theme using Material Bootstrap Design (MDB), a Material variant that uses Bootstrap 4 plus its own code.

It [calls for](http://mdbootstrap.com/mdb-quick-start/) using the following scripts...

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/tether.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
```

I had simply added these to the bottom of my `footer.php`. But now I have read that I should add Javascripts to WordPress properly, ie, by enqueuing.

So far, I have used this...

```
// Add Javascripts for my Bootstrap theme
function bootstrap_scripts_with_jquery()
{
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstra-jquery', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mdb/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-jquery-min', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mdb/js/jquery.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mdb/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-material', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/mdb/js/mdb.min.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_scripts_with_jquery' );
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583978/how-to-load-bootstrap-script-and-style-in-functions-php-wordpress
```

This works, to a point - it adds my four lines to the code (though I don't know if doing it this way makes any difference).

However, I also see two remaining/default JS lines in my header that I didn't add...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/jquery.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/bootstrap.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/blankslate/mdb/js/mdb.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
```

And I am still seeing this line in the footer, though I didn't add it (I think I want to leave this, right?)...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.6.1'></script>
```

The main question, then, is - how should I deal with the fact that WordPress includes `jquery.js?ver=1.12.4` and `jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1` when my theme does not call for them?
Is there a conflict here?
If WordPress' own JQuery is being served by passing a version number to it, is it possible that I can force it to use v2.2.3 as requested by my theme? And what about this "migrate" version?

I'm aware that you can dequeue scripts, and have read that you can [force a custom version using a filter](https://www.webhostinghero.com/change-the-jquery-version-wordpress/) [or similar](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/replacing-default-wordpress-scripts/?utm_expid=3606929-91.15T0nlf8TFCqo1W_BlZjGg.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F). But I have also read that you should not be tinkering with removing WordPress' default version of JQuery.

I am confused.

And do I need to enqueue CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress loads jQuery because plugins and themes suppose it does. If you want another version of jQuery for your theme, there is a risk that plugins you may be using will not work, since (if they are maintained well) they are designed to work [with default jquery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/244537/why-does-wordpress-use-outdated-jquery-v1-12-4/244543#244543).

That said, if you insist on using your own version of jQuery you can easily deregister it, as you found out. If you're not planning a public release of your theme you can control the consequences.

And yes, you should [enqueue styles](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) as well. The reason to do this, is it allows you to set dependencies, which is important if (for instance) you would want to make a child theme and deregister the parent styles.

Comment: But, if the Bootstrap framework stuff I am using asks for 2.2.3, don't I also risk THAT not working? ie. Can I ensure that both WordPress/plugins and my Bootstrap stuff work? Maybe by adding both lines?

Comment: Yes, you're facing a difficult choice. Loading two versions of jQuery may cause troubles as well. So whichever option you choose, some rigorous testing across multiple browsers will be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not that much of a WordPress question after all. But as far as I have seen the Bootstrap 4 works with jQuery 1.2.0. Tested Simon Padburys [Bootstrap 4 Starter Theme](https://github.com/SimonPadbury/b4st) for WordPress which enqueue WordPress onboard (pre-registered) jQuery.

https://github.com/SimonPadbury/b4st/blob/master/functions/enqueues.php

Comment: If I comment-out my two added jquery files, Javascript nav tabs stop working.

Comment: Note: Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 requires jQuery >=1.9.1, see the package.json file from the [official repository](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/package.json#L69).