# JQuery script working locally on desktop, not working on Wordpress + Divi

Tags: jquery, html, code, map

So I have to map an image, and I chose to use jQuery. The code works perfectly on my desktop, in the browser, code editors, etc. But whenever I try to port it to the WordPress website I'm managing (using Divi 4.6.6), it doesn't work.

I used the same code for both versions, except for the WP one using jQuery instead of the dollar sign for functions and selectors, because otherwise, WordPress won't recognize them.

**UPDATE:** jQuery is not noticing the events set for the "area" tags in WP, although it does locally. This is the main problem.

Here's the code in question. It's supposed to show a popup whenever the user hovers the cursor on specific parts of the image:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#popup").hide();
  $("area").mouseleave(function(){$("#popup").hide()})
$('area').mouseenter(function(event)
{ 
$("#popup").show()
$('#popup').css("top",event.pageY)
$('#popup').css("left",event.pageX)
;})
})});
```

Comment: What happens if you don't wait a second time for `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: Nothing happens, I removed the embedding and used jQuery.() as it is, but after some debugging, I figured out the problem is WP is not noticing the "area" tags being clicked. (I'm going to edit the question with this new info)

Comment: Which jQuery versions are you testing with? WordPress's default one is 1.12, which is reasonably old. Can you reproduce this with 1.12 on your desktop?

Comment: I'll try. Is there any way to update it?

Comment: Here's a question about that: [Update jquery version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/257317/update-jquery-version)

Comment: It actually works with jQuery 1.12.0, but back in WP, the "area" elements seem to be ignored by the selector. More precisely, they're interpreted as no width, no height elements.